# Path for assets in DXA 1.7 . Do not want tcm id appended to the image while accessing it

Tags: dxa

In Publication properties, I changed the value for `Images Path` and `Images URL` to `\media\mysite` and `/media/mysite/`

While publishing the image, it is stored in the Broker database by appending tcmid to the image name

I am able to access it, if I append Publication ID to the path  `http://{domain}/media/mysite/{image-name}_tcmxx-xx.jpg`

But I don't want TCM URI appended to the images name 
ex: `http://{domain}/media/mysite/{image-name}.png`.

Actually we also tried writing custom code (TBB), in DB it is storing in proper format but when I am retrieving the image it is appending with `./index` at the end.

Please help on this. Is there any other alternatives without TCM URI appending?

Comment: Try storage extension. That will be the best option for this kind of requirement.

Answer (score 2):

`+1` for what Sayantan said.

Now, This behavior avoids duplicacy of binaries and is default nature. It also appends width & height in some case `(Ex: ballon-burner_tcm5-258_w1024_h311_n.jpg)`.

**Little bit of background on this**

The Default Finish Action Template contains a TBB called - `Publish binaries for component` It uses a [PublishBinariesComponent](https://github.com/dd4t/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/blob/master/dotnet/DD4T.Templates/PublishBinariesComponent.cs#L74), which calls [ConstructFileName](https://github.com/dd4t/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/blob/29bfc01643093398fe3404db56bf0219919697df/dotnet/DD4T.Templates.Base/Utils/BinaryPublisher.cs#L161) of [BinaryPublisher](https://github.com/dd4t/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/blob/29bfc01643093398fe3404db56bf0219919697df/dotnet/DD4T.Templates.Base/Utils/BinaryPublisher.cs).

```
    private static string ConstructFileName(Component mmComp, string variantId)
    {
        Regex re = new Regex(@"^(.*)\.([^\.]+)$");
        string fileName = mmComp.BinaryContent.Filename;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
        }
        return re.Replace(fileName, string.Format("$1_{0}_{1}.$2", mmComp.Id.ToString().Replace(":", ""), variantId.Replace(":", "")));
    }
```

This method returns the binary file name at Rendering -
 `engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary()`. One of the overload method `AddBinary(Stream, String, String, Component, String)` also give liberty to set filename of your choice but this is limited i believe.

Look at the [code](https://github.com/dd4t/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/blob/29bfc01643093398fe3404db56bf0219919697df/dotnet/DD4T.Templates.Base/Utils/BinaryPublisher.cs#L153) below:
If you see the `else` part - `ConstructFileName(mmComp, currentTemplate.Id)` is called when `targetStructureGroupUri` is not null, this value comes from your parameter schema of `Publish binaries for component` TBB.

```
    if (targetStructureGroupUri == null)
    {   
    ....
    Binary binary = engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary(mmComp);
    publishedPath = binary.Url;
    log.Debug(string.Format("binary is published to url {0}", publishedPath));
    }
    else
    {
    Component mmComp = (Component)engine.GetObject(item.Properties[Item.ItemPropertyTcmUri]);
    string fileName = ConstructFileName(mmComp, currentTemplate.Id);
    StructureGroup targetSG = (StructureGroup)engine.GetObject(targetStructureGroupUri);
    itemStream = item.GetAsStream();
    ....
    log.Debug(string.Format("publishing mm component {0} to structure group {1} with variant id {2} and filename {3}", mmComp.Id, targetStructureGroupUri.ToString(), currentTemplate.Id, fileName));
    Binary b = engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary(item.GetAsStream(), fileName, targetSG, currentTemplate.Id, mmComp, mmComp.BinaryContent.MultimediaType.MimeType);
    publishedPath = b.Url;    
    log.Debug(string.Format("binary is published to url {0}", publishedPath));
    }
```

So if you write a TBB (Create your custom default finish action Template) and add it.. right after **Publish Binary for Component TBB** to process received **Output** from `Publish binaries for component`TBB then you might have some chance. The output should have `publishedPath` which is what you would need to get to your desired url.

Your `Publish binaries for component` parameter schema has all the values i guess which is used in the final binary url. Specially `sg_PublishBinariesTargetStructureGroup` value in your case.

There could be better ways indeed.

Comment: The reason why the file names (and URLs) of Binaries are suffixed with a TCM URI (or actually something that resembles a TCM URI) is to ensure that the file name (and URL) is sufficiently unique to distinguish it from other Binaries.

The first part of the file name is taken from the (original) file name of the Binary Content of the Multimedia Component. However, the system does not enforce that those (original) file names are unique.  Since (by default) all Binaries are published in the same location, only the (original) file name may not be sufficiently unique.